# Error using Microsoft SAPI and Allegro C++ library together

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text-to-speech, sapi, allegro

I created a simple TTS program in VisualC++ in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 using Microsoft SAPI and the program is working fine, but as soon as I'am including #include Allegro.h header file to do some graphical works, the compiler throws following errors:

a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\allegro\system.h(31): error C2371: 'BITMAP' : redefinition; different basic types

1>          a:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\wingdi.h(606) : see declaration of 'BITMAP'

1>a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\allegro\debug.h(39): warning C4005: 'ASSERT' : macro redefinition

1>          a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(372) : see previous definition of 'ASSERT'

1>a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\allegro\debug.h(40): warning C4005: 'TRACE' : macro redefinition

1>          a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(338) : see previous definition of 'TRACE'

1>a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\allegro\platform\alwin.h(49): error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

1>          a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio12.0\vc\include\allegro\platform\alwin.h(49) : see declaration of 'WinMain'

1>a:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio

12.0\vc\include\allegro\platform\alwin.h(49): error C2733: 'WinMain' : second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed

1>          a:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\winbase.h(905) : see declaration of 'WinMain'

But when i'am using the same allegro.h header files in other programs not using Microsoft SAPI, the program works fine.

Comment: Allegro 4.x unfortunately defines a type `BITMAP` on global namespace, which is also defined by Windows headers... Is there a possibility you could use newer versions of Allegro? The just released version 5.2 and is available through Visual Studio NuGet for easy installation

Comment: I installed Allegro 5.2 using nuget and got the following result:           PM> Install-Package Allegro
Attempting to resolve dependency 'AllegroDeps (= 1.4.0)'.
Installing 'AllegroDeps 1.4.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'AllegroDeps 1.4.0.0'.
Installing 'Allegro 5.2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Allegro 5.2.0.0'.
Adding 'AllegroDeps 1.4.0.0' to news2.
Successfully added 'AllegroDeps 1.4.0.0' to news2.
Adding 'Allegro 5.2.0.0' to news2.
Successfully added 'Allegro 5.2.0.0' to news2.                                         Now after this I #include<allegro5.h> and got the same set of errors.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. After successful installation of Allegro 5.2 via Nuget and including "tchar.h" file i'am getting following errors:                                              1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: news2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  news2.cpp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>A:\Users\Mohit Mishra\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\news2\Debug\news2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
===== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==